# Running a .jar file with jdk 1.8.0

Tags: java, jdk, oracle, jar

I installed JDK 1.8.0 from Oracle, and everything works perfectly. I can create, compile and run java files. But I just downloaded a .jar file and tried running it using `java -jar path/name.jar` and it gave me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/i386/libawt_xawt.so: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Whats happening?

Here is my current Java alternative path.

```
Selection    Path                                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/bin/java   1         auto mode
  1            /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java       1         manual mode
* 2            /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/bin/java   1         manual mode
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `libawt_xawt.so` requires `libXext.so.6` but can't find it.

To fix it, try: `sudo apt install --reinstall libxext6`

Source: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libXext.so.6&mode=filename&suite=raring&arch=any

Comment: It says its unable to locate that package

Comment: The package name is libxext6 : `sudo apt-get install libxext6`  http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libxext6libxext-dev

Comment: Okay did it but I reinstalled twice but keep getting the same error message from the jar file.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Sorry, fixed

Comment: @PythonandAndroidforlife can you post the output of `ls -lah /usr/lib/*-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6`? (if the other answer didn't solve the problem)

Comment: teh following `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Oct 25  2014 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 -> libXext.so.6.4.0`

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem you dont have libXext.so.6 so try reinstalling it with this command

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libxext6
```

Or if that doesn't work:

```
sudo apt remove libxext 
sudo apt install libxext
```

If even that doesn't work:

```
sudo apt purge libxext 
sudo apt install libxext
```

This should work :)